# Basis of an eigenspace and eigenvectors

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Since the degeneracy of an eigenvalue is defined as the "maximum number of linearly independent eigenvectors" and a basis of a vectorial space could be defined also as "the set formed by the maximum number of linearly independent vectors" or "the maximal linearly independent set", in order to find a basis of an eigenspace, am I just supposed to find the eigenvectors of an eigenvalue?

For example, an eigenvalue of degeneracy $2$ will have at most two linearly independent eigenvectors, so if I find 'em I will have a basis of the eigenspace?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right. Find "all the eigenvectors" associated with an eigenvalue gives you a basis of the eigenspace

Comment: @BenGrossmann Sorry, all the eigenvectors or the linearly independent one's? Because in one eigenspace I think we can find infinite eigenvectors.

Comment: I mean a full linearly independent set of eigenvectors